# Adding Flutter module to existing App via Cocoapods

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I want to rework part of our app in Flutter. I plan to use Flutter module. The official docs explains how to get it working ([here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup)). The offered solutions are:

- Option A - Embed with CocoaPods and the Flutter SDK
- Option B - Embed frameworks in Xcode
- Option C - Embed application and plugin frameworks in Xcode and Flutter framework with CocoaPods

Each of these options has it drawbacks when having multiple teams (some of which will not use Flutter at all). Option C is perhaps the closest to what we need but the App framework (and plugin dependencies) must be embedded manually.

Is it possible (and how it could be done) to have both App frameworks and Flutter framework added via Cocoapods?

The benefits of this solution would be:

1. Team members not working with Flutter would not have to install Flutter in order to work on the app
2. Team members working with Flutter would distribute the new version with greater ease and not be required to change all App framework files manually.
3. The git repo would not be required to save the App framework files and grow to large

Comment: Unfortunately no, we ran out of time to solve this. Will give it another go at a later date.